# Pthread Specific Data In Linux System

Tags: c, pthreads, systems-programming

In the Linux System we can use pthread for multithread programming and in the pthread there was a pthread specific data where we should first create a key. But what is the purpose of pthread specific data, i have done use google and chatgpt to knowing for what is this but i don't understand. Does this same like thread local storage ?

Comment: Do you mean the last argument (of type `void *`) of `pthread_create` that gets passed to the thread start routine? It is used to pass a pointer value from the place that created the thread to the created thread. It is up to the parties involved what the pointer actually points to.

Comment: @IanAbbott, I am fairly confident that they are talking about `pthread_key_create()` / `pthread_setspecific()` / `pthread_getspecific()`.

Answer (score 1):

> in the pthread there was a pthread specific data where we should first create a key.

I take you to mean data accessed via `pthread_setspecific()` and `pthread_getspecific()`, using keys created via `pthread_key_create()`.

> Does this same like thread local storage ?

Yes, pthreads thread-specific data is a form of thread-local storage.  The data accessed via a given key is specific to the thread in which it is accessed.  Different threads each access their own.

Additionally, it is possible to associate a destructor function with the key, which will be used, separately by each thread, to clean up the object associated with that key in that thread when the thread terminates.

Since C11, standard C has the `_Thread_local` qualifier that provides a different, simpler mechanism, but does not have a provision for destructor function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation sir, but sir just say i have 2 thread. Then i have done use the pthreads thread-specific data in both thread. Suppose the thread 1 have data 10 that have been associate with the key and also the thread 2 have data 20 that have been associate with the key also. Then suppose thread 1 want to accesss data 20 from thread 2, does Is this possible ?,We use the pthreads thread-specific to access data 20 from the thread 20

Comment: You mean "how can I use thread-specific data in a way not specific to the thread"? You can always just pass the pointer or value from one thread to another, but it seems perverse.

Comment: @ApabilaXTerkadang, one thread cannot directly access the thread-specific data of another.  Data that you want to access from multiple threads should usually be stored in ordinary shared variables, or in objects accessible via the thread function's argument.